# Mule flows - tracing the path between the flows

Tags: java, xml, mule, jms, mule-flow

I was given a ton of xml files containing mule flows and I was asked to understand the process and draw diagrams showing the message paths between the flows.

As I am looking at these flows I am seeing inbound endpoints, some logging/ transformations, then outbound endpoints. My question is how do I determine the source of the inbound endpoints? Are these inbound endpoints coming as outbound endpoints from other flows, and if they are what should I be looking for to determine what flows these are coming from and going to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain mate.

If you're seeing inbound endpoint to in a flow, then that gives you clue of which calling which. For example if its a VM connector, then you can look at which queue/topic is assign to it, then look at the entire project's mule flows, where its being called. However if its just a private flow (without the endpoint) You will then need to search for the flow-ref call for it.

Another thing you can do, is run it in debug mode if you can in your Anypoint Studio, ensure that you have put a breakpoint to it, then do a step-by-step run. You may need to do this if there are several scenarios for every inbound payload.